# Github上で「あるべきファイル」が無いとき（削除？リネーム？）、調べる方法はありますか？

Tags: git, github

LaravelのBreezeの「日本語化」をするにあたり、必要なファイルが「github」に公開されているということでした。

[【Laravel+Breeze】はじめから学ぶアプリの作りかた－英会話教室管理アプリを作ろう](https://mmsankosho.com/post-17960/#toc5)
[Laravel Breezeのインストールと日本語化](https://qiita.com/min0727/items/04562f34bb2c65f99bd5)

書かれている手順の通り、ダウンロードしたり、該当フォルダを確認したのですが、**必要なファイル `ja.json` がありません**
https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/tree/main/locales/ja
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

検索でこのレポジトリー内を調べると、commit,issueには登場してきましたが、codeにはありませんでした

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**「無い」ということは、削除されたか、リネームされたか、だと思います。**
しかし、commit,issueにはそのような形跡を見つけることが出来ません。

そこでタイトルの質問となりますが
**「目的のファイルはどうなったのか？（削除された、リネームされた等）」**
を知る方法はあるでしょうか？

---

最終の状態にたどり着く方法として…

1. 目的のファイル名を検索（このレポジトリー）
2. [最終コミットのタイトルをクリック](https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/search?q=ja.json&type=commits)
3. [[Browse files]をクリック](https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/commit/5096ca7a4d4eaab4fa03a47ab9b0da23c04068cf)
4. (このコミットしたときの状態に移動）
5. [go to file]をクリック
6. 目的のファイル名を検索
7. ファイル名をクリック
   という手順でたどり着くことが出来ました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 参考: 当該の変更は[cecfd091](https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/commit/cecfd091c7f8fbfe0e4906a5a9986914dc4937b1)で行われています。この変更については[リリースノート](https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/releases/tag/11.0.0)でも触れられていますね。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

今回のような例であれば、最新のプロジェクトで消えたファイルの名前がわかっているので容易に追跡することができますが、そうでなくても比較的容易にGitHub上で追跡できそうな方法の一例を紹介します。

たとえば、今回追跡したいのは `main` ブランチにかつて存在した `locales/ja/ja.json` です。

かつて存在した、ということがわかっているのでまずは存在しそうな過去のリビジョンを見てみましょう。今回のようなパッケージであれば、各バージョンにタグが振られているので容易に過去のリビジョンを遡れます。試しに、`10.8.0`の`locales/ja/`を見てみましょう。以下のURLです。

https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/tree/10.8.0/locales/ja

[image: 10.8.0 tree locales/ja]

たしかに、想定通り`ja.json`が存在しています。開いて、右上のHistoryから履歴を開いてみましょう。
[image]

https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/commits/10.8.0/locales/ja/ja.json

この時点ではまだ10.8.0の時点での履歴です。ここからがマジックです。

上記URLのタグの部分、つまり`10.8.0`を目的の最新ブランチ、つまり`main`で置き換えてみましょう。

https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang/commits/main/locales/ja/ja.json

すでに存在しないファイルについても、履歴を追うことができるんです。すでにツリーに存在しないファイルということは、ここで最新のコミットは削除や移動を含んでいるコミットということです。また、このコミットの直前(=parent)のツリーを見れば直前の状況もよくわかります。

今回はGitHub上で試しましたが、`git log` コマンドでも同様の操作が可能なはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。まさに求めていた方法です。とてもありがたい情報です。

Comment: バージョン（タグ）については[main▼]をクリックして[Tags]を表示。適当なものを選択して、見つけるという流れですね